# Comparing two tables that doesn't have unique key

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare two tables data and check which attributed are mismatching, tables have same table definition, but the problem is i dint have a unique key to compare. I tried to use

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(table1.A, Table1.B))
=CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(table2.A, Table2.B))
```

but still facing duplicate rows also tried NVL on few columns but didn't work

```
SELECT  
    UT.cat,
    PD.cat
FROM 
    EM UT, EM_63 PD 
WHERE 
    NVL(UT.cat, 1) = NVL(PD.cat, 1) AND
    NVL(UT.AT_NUMBER, 1) = NVL(PD.AT_NUMBER, 1) AND
    NVL(UT.OFFSET, 1) = NVL(PD.OFFSET, 1) AND  
    NVL(UT.PROD, 1) = NVL(PD.PROD, 1)
;
```

There are 34k records in one table 35k records in another table, but if I run the above query, the count of rows is 3 millions.

Columns in table:

```
COUNTRY       
CATEGORY   
TYPE    
DESCRIPTION
```

Sample data :

Table 1 :

```
COUNTRY  CATEGORY TYPE   DESCRIPTION       
US          C       T1      In
IN          A       T2      OUT
B           C       T2      IN
Y           C       T1      INOUT
```

Table 2:

```
COUNTRY  CATEGORY TYPE   DESCRIPTION    
US          C       T2      In
IN          B        T2     Out
Q           C       T2      IN
```

Expected output:

```
column      Matched  unmatched
COUNTRY         2       1
CATEGORY        2       1
TYPE            2       1
DESCRIPTION     3       0
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Maybe `except` will help

Comment: why triple concats?

Comment: Are trying to find rows in table1 that are not in table2?

Comment: update you question adding a data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: You can use this set: `(A-B) U (B-A)` = `(select * from A minus select * from B) union (select * from B minus select * from A)`

Comment: The above statement is also equal to set `(AUB) - (A^B)` = `(select * from A union select * from B) minus (select * from A intersect select * from B)`

Comment: @Cunning tested with both, obtaining duplicate rows, fetching 67k records

Comment: @ Nir Levy : trying to merge 4 attibutes to form a key..

Comment: Sounds like you've made assumptions about your data that are not true. Look at the actual data you are joining, and the result.

Comment: @Varoo - while Cunning's suggestions will not give you the most efficient execution, they should give you the correct result. What do you mean by "duplicate rows" - UNION, INTERSECT and MINUS eliminate duplicates, so you must be using the word "duplicates" incorrectly, or you didn't implement the suggestions correctly.

Comment: @Varoo I think you are trying to match only certain columns. If this is the case, just substitute `*` in queries with the list of columns you want to be checked in the same order everywhere. else oracle may typecast your columns pair by pair and tries to match them, if not matched, they will be in the result. The Venn diagram looks like this `(A***(#) ***B)`. You get * part but not # part, as a set (no duplicate if ALL columns in column number order match.

Comment: **After your edits**: So, you are really only comparing one column at a time - and at the end you are pulling all the answers together in one report. I don't see how this helps you. It doesn't tell you WHICH values don't match. It doesn't even tell you how many unmatched values are in the first table and how many in the second. And most importantly, it doesn't match by row. All your results may show zero unmatched values in all columns, and yet the two tables may have no rows in common. Are you 100% sure you thought deeply about this requirement? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: The basic idea is that we are validating our data against production data so if there are any mismatches we will check that attibutes and fix the code for populating that attribute properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most general case (when you may have duplicate rows, and you want to see which rows exist in one table but not in the other, and ALSO which rows may exist in both tables, but the row exists 3 times in the first table but 5 times in the other):

This is a very common problem with a settled "best solution" which for some reason it seems most people are still not aware of, even though it was developed on AskTom many years ago and has been presented numerous times.

You do NOT need a join, you do not need a unique key of any kind, and you don't need to read either table more than once. The idea is to add two columns to show from which table each row comes, do a UNION ALL, then GROUP BY all the columns except the "source" columns and show the count for each table. Something like this:

```
select   count(t_1) as count_table_1, count(t_2) as count_table_2, col1, col2, ...
from     (
           select 'x' as t_1, null as t_2, col1, col2, ... 
             from table_1
           union all
           select null as t_1, 'x' as t_2, col1, col2, ...
             from table_2
         )
group by col1, col2, ...
having   count(t_1) != count(t_2)
;
```

Comment: thanks for the sugestion, but can we get the ouput like Columnname,matched count,unmatchedcount

Comment: @varoo - what do you mean by "matched count"? And you want to do this by column? I am not sure that makes sense. Please post a small sample of what the result should look like (don't worry about how it can be achieved) and what it means.

Comment: Updated the sample data

Answer (score 1):

Start with this query to check if these 4 columns form a key.

```
select      occ_total,occ_ut,occ_pd
           ,count(*)                as records

from       (select      count (*)                               as occ_total
                       ,count (case tab when 'UT' then 1 end)   as occ_ut
                       ,count (case tab when 'PD' then 1 end)   as occ_pd

            from                    select 'UT' as tab,cat,AT_NUMBER,OFFSET,PROD from EM
                        union all   select 'PD'       ,cat,AT_NUMBER,OFFSET,PROD from EM_63 PD
                        ) t

            group by    cat,AT_NUMBER,OFFSET,PROD
            ) t

group by    occ_total,occ_ut,occ_pd     

order by    records desc
;
```

After you have chosen your "key",you can use the following query to see the attributes' values

```
select      count (*)                               as occ_total
           ,count (case tab when 'UT' then 1 end)   as occ_ut
           ,count (case tab when 'PD' then 1 end)   as occ_pd

           ,count (distinct att1)                   as cnt_dst_att1
           ,count (distinct att2)                   as cnt_dst_att2
           ,count (distinct att3)                   as cnt_dst_att3
           ,...
           ,listagg (case tab when 'UT' then att1 end) within group (order by att1) as att1_vals_ut
           ,listagg (case tab when 'PD' then att1 end) within group (order by att1) as att1_vals_pd
           ,listagg (case tab when 'UT' then att2 end) within group (order by att2) as att2_vals_ut
           ,listagg (case tab when 'PD' then att2 end) within group (order by att2) as att2_vals_pd
           ,listagg (case tab when 'UT' then att3 end) within group (order by att3) as att3_vals_ut
           ,listagg (case tab when 'PD' then att3 end) within group (order by att3) as att3_vals_pd  
           ,...

from                    select 'UT' as tab,cat,AT_NUMBER,OFFSET,PROD,att1,att2,att3,... from E M
            union all   select 'PD'       ,cat,AT_NUMBER,OFFSET,PROD,att1,att2,att3,... from EM_63 PD
            ) t

group by    cat,AT_NUMBER,OFFSET,PROD
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `CONCAT`is, that you could get invalid matches, if your data looks similar to this:

```
table1.A = '123'
table1.B = '456'
```

concatenates to: `'123456'`

```
table2.A = '12'
table2.B = '3456'
```

concatenates also to: `'123456'`

You have to compare the fields individually: `table1.A = table2.A AND table1.B = table2.B`

Comment: I have tried comparing table1.A =table2.A ,but i need count(*) of the differing data too.